# Find rows that match all or some of the where clause conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

If I have a table(`widgets`) with boolean columns like `is_blue`, and `is_hard` and some string columns like `region` and `kind`.

I can do a query like the following to get rows that match all the conditions

```
select * from widgets 
where is_hard = true
and is_blue = false
and region = 'NYC'
and kind = 'Deluxe';
```

If I also wanted to find widgets that meet 3/4 of the criteria or 2/4 and so on.
Is that something I can do in SQL in one query? Or would I have to iterate in my code making less and less specific queries? I'm most familiar with Postgres and Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use below query. The sample query will return result that meet 3/4 of the criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM   widgets
WHERE  3 = (CASE WHEN is_hard = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         + (CASE WHEN is_blue = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         + (CASE WHEN region = 'NYC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         + (CASE WHEN kind = 'Deluxe' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This being Postgres, we can shorten the `where` clause to: `3 = is_hard::int + is_blue::int + (region = 'NYC')::int + (kind = 'Deluxe)::int`